# .htaccess - redirect folder url to a file, and keep original address in address bar, whether the original url had a trailing slash or not

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

If a user goes to a URL formatted to look like a directory (http://www.example.com/myfolder/) I need the webserver to display a file and pass the folder name into the querystring, so it actually loads (http://www.example.com/file.php?folder=myfolder)

I have got this working if a user types in (http://www.example.com/myfolder/), but if they type in (http://www.example.com/myfolder) then it the address bar changes to (http://www.example.com/file.php?folder=myfolder)

How can I make this work whether the user types a trailing slash or not, and at the same time, keeping the original folder url displayed in the address bar?

I had it working previously, but my .htaccess got corrupt and I am having to rewrite it again due to the backup being overwritten.

Here is the contents of my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !activate [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /file.php?folder=$1 [L]
```